# Как в PUG добавить ссылки в переменную

Tags: pug

```
- var values = [];
ul
  each val in values.length ? values : ['Home', 'documentation', 'about']
    li= val
```

Как вместо строк добавить ссылки.

Например, вместо Home было a(href='home.html') Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, передать массив объектов:

```
- let values = [];

ul
  each item in values.length ? values : [{link: 'home.html', title: 'Home'}, {link: 'documentation.html', title: 'documentation'}, {link: 'about.html', title: 'about'}]
    - const {link, title} = item
    li
      a(href= link)= title
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!